# How can I use addhour for custom date?

Tags: bash, date

I have a string from conf file (lets call for example date1):

```
#!/bin/bash
# it is example
date1="201605250925"

datenow="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M -d "+1hour")"

date2=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M -d "$date1 + 1hour")
# NOT WORK?
echo "$date1 --> $date2"
# WORK!
echo "$date1 --> $datenow"
```

I need to add 1 hour. But getting error like this:

```
date: invalid date `201605250925 + 1hour'
```

But its work for `datenow`.

How can I user addhour for custom date format from string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a format that meets the command `date` expectations, something like:

```
2016-05-25 09:25
```

The space denote the start of time and the time format is HH:MM.
That comes from then [international ISO 8601](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html), but using an space instead of a T.

If the format is fixed, we can use bash internal capacities (no external command except date used) to change it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
d1="201605250925"

dc="${d1:0:8} ${d1:8:2}:${d1:10:2}+0"
d2=$(date +'%Y%m%d %H:%M' -ud "$dc + 1 hour" )
echo "$d2"
```

Or **POSIX**ly (dash) with no call needed to sed, awk or cut (faster):

```
#!/bin/dash
d1="201605250925"

dt=${d1##????????}

dc="${d1%%"$dt"} ${dt%%??}:${dt##??}+0"
d2=$(date -ud "$dc + 1 hour" +'%Y%m%d %H:%M')
echo "$d2"
```

---

```
20160525 10:25
```

The inclusion of a `+0` after the time in `dc`: `20160525 09:25+0`
will ensure that `date` will interpret the time as with offset 0 (UTC).

The use of the option `-u` to date will ensure that the value read in UTC also change in UTC, avoiding any Daylight correction or local time change.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the same format as your input string you could use `cut` or `sed` to split it:

**[`cut`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cut-invocation.html#cut-invocation)**

```
d1="201605250925"
ds=$(echo $d1 | cut --output-delimiter=" " -c 1-8,9-12); \
d2=$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M' -ud "$ds + 1hour")
```

**[`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)**

```
d1="201605250925"
ds=$(echo $d1 | sed 's/\(.*\)\(....\)$/\1 \2/g'); \
d2=$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M' -ud "$ds + 1hour")
```

This way the **[`date`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Examples-of-date.html)** utility can make sense of the date and time.

**Result:**

```
$ echo $d2
201605251025
```